# sequelize hasMany, how to use customized foreginKey

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

**Model EmployeeView**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var _this = sequelize.define('EmployeeView', {
    employeeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: 'code'
    },
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: 'emailaddress'
    },
    department: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: 'department_name'
    },
    departmentId: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      field: 'departments_id'
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'employees_view',
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        _this.belongsTo(models.EmployeeCategory, {
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'employeecategories_id'
          }
        });
        _this.hasMany(models.EmployeeFile, {
          foreignKey: 'employees_code'
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return _this;
};
```

**Model EmployeeFile**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var _this = sequelize.define("EmployeeFile", {
    employeeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: 'employees_code'
    },
    filename: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      filed: 'filename'
    },
    employeeFileTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      field: 'employee_file_types_id'
    }
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'employee_files'
  });

  return _this;
};
```

**Router**

```
router.get('/employee', function(req, res) {
  models.EmployeeView.findAll({
    where: {
      active: req.query.active
    }
    include: [{
      model: models.EmployeeCategory
    }, {
      model: models.EmployeeFile,
       }]
  }).then(function(employee) {
    res.json(employee);
  });
});
```

### What do I expect to happen?

I have two tables '**employee_view**' (*it is a view*) and '**employee_files**' which map to the '**EmployeeView**' and '**EmployeeFile**'. '**employee_view**' has '**id**' field as the primary key and '**code**' field as the employee number.'**employee_files**' has '**employees_code**' as its primary key and foreignKey which bindings with the '**code**' field. So I want to get '**employee_files**' data through this relation.

### What is actually happening?

Actually,I got nothing. Because the sequelize will execute "EmployeeView.id == EmployeeFile.employees_code". But I want the sequelize to execute "EmployeeView.code == EmployeeFile.employees_code" .What should I do?

Comment: it EmployeeView.id == EmployeeFile.employees_code because the primary key of your EmployeeView is therefore you must set EmployeeView.employees_code as primary key in your node JS Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `primaryKey: true` to your employeeId field to link the EmployeeView to EmployeeFiles since the belongsToMany relationship will only link to the primary key of it's parent

```
employeeId: {
  type: sequelize.INTEGER,
  field: 'code',
  primaryKey: true
},
```